# How to change the background behind a presented view?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am presenting a sheet in my project but I would like to change the opacity/color of the background behind the view presented. (the red area in the screenshot)

Example screenshot:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
@State var presentElement: Bool = false

var body: some View {
  Text("Present el")
    .onTapGesture {
      presentElement = true
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $presentElement) {
            NotifActionModal()
            .background() {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Path { path in
                        frameSize = geometry.size.height 
                    }
                }
            }
            .presentationDetents([.height(frameSize)])
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are already using a state variable to capture the height of the sheet. So if you know the height of the sheet, you can deduct it from the heght of the base view. Then when the sheet is showing, you can change its background if you want to.

Like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var presentElement: Bool = false
    @State private var frameSize = CGFloat.zero
    @State private var maxBodyHeight = CGFloat.infinity

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            Text("Present el")
                .frame(
                    maxWidth: .infinity,
                    maxHeight: presentElement
                        ? proxy.size.height - frameSize - 20
                        : proxy.size.height
                )
                .background(
                    (presentElement ? Color.blue : Color.red)
                        .opacity(0.05)
                )
                .border(.red, width: 4)
                .onTapGesture {
                    presentElement = true
                }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $presentElement) {
            Text("NotifActionModal")
                .frame(height: 200)
                .background() {
                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                        Path { path in
                            frameSize = geometry.size.height
                        }
                    }
                }
                .presentationDetents([.height(frameSize)])
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Sheet]

Comment: This is a nice approach. So we can't directly interact with the background already present by the sheet?

Comment: Ah, you mean the gray mask that covers the base view in the region above the sheet? I don't think there is any way to control this. But you can control everything under the mask and of course the contents of the sheet too. From iOS 16.4 onwards you can change the sheet background using ```.presentationBackground```. You can also set a material as background, see [SwiftUI: System Material as Background on Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77011069/20386264).

Comment: Yes the grey mask exactly. Well I'll try to find a work around then!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to accomplish with the Path { _ in } within the background of the sheet but regarding opacity of the background of the sheet :

- As @Benzy Need said you have a presentElement state you can use to trigger ui changes.
- The background modifier that needs to be updated, If I understood the question correctly is the one behind the sheet with the presentation detents.

From theses assumptions here are relatively easy ways to accomplish this, here are three, all are based the presentElement state change.

```
@State var presentElement: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.red.opacity(presentElement ? 0.3 : 1))
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .overlay {
            Text("Present el")
        }
    .animation(.default, value: presentElement)
    .onTapGesture {
        presentElement = true
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $presentElement) {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .overlay {
                Text("Modal")
            }
            .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.3)])
    }
}
```

In this one you use a Rectangle() to fill up the space that's behind the sheet and presentElement has changed, the opacity of the rectangle changes but not the overlay. The overlay can be anything.

```
@State var presentElement: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        Spacer()
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Present el")
            Spacer()
        }
        Spacer()
        
    }
    .background {
        Color.red
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .opacity(presentElement ? 0.8 : 1)
    }
    .animation(.easeIn, value: presentElement)
    .onTapGesture {
        presentElement = true
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $presentElement) {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .overlay {
                Text("Modal")
            }
            .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.3)])
    }
}
```

As you can the second example works the exact same as the first one, what changes is the "Root content" instead of being a Rectangle() we filled up the spaces of the screen with stacks. And as before the presentElement variable triggers the background change.

[image: Both results in :]

```
@State var presentElement: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        Spacer()
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Present el")
            Spacer()
        }
        Spacer()
        
    }
    .background {
        Color.red
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .overlay {
                Color.black
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .opacity(presentElement ? 0.2 : 0)

            }
    }
    .animation(.easeIn, value: presentElement)
    .onTapGesture {
        presentElement = true
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $presentElement) {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .overlay {
                Text("Modal")
            }
            .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.3)])
    }
}
```

In this one we apply the "dark effect" one the content background itself.
and it works exactly as the preview ones.

[image: With the dark effect]

Note: If you want to change the opacity of the content apply the opacity modifier to the "content" as well.

**EDIT**

If we want to avoid the automatic gray effect we need to not use the sheet(_) modifier and use directly a custom view, that will be shown when the state is updated as previously and by using the transition() modifier, or an offset/opacity modifier to give a nice effect.

```
struct Content: View {
    @State var presentElement: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        let rectangleColor = presentElement ? Color.purple.opacity(0.4)
        : Color.clear
        Rectangle()
            .fill(rectangleColor)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .overlay{
                Text("Present el")
            }
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                presentElement.toggle()
            }
        }
        .showModal(presentElement, modalHeight: 200, modal: {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .overlay {
                    Text("Modal")
                }
        })
    }
}

struct ModalTypeView<Modal: View>: ViewModifier {
    var isPresented: Bool
    let modalHeight: CGFloat
    @ViewBuilder var modal: () -> Modal
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                    modal()
                    .frame(height: modalHeight)
                    .opacity(isPresented ? 1 : 0)
                    .offset(y:isPresented ? 0 : 1000)
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    func showModal<Modal: View>(_ condition: Bool,
                   modalHeight: CGFloat,
                   modal: @escaping () -> Modal) -> some View {
        modifier(ModalTypeView(
            isPresented: condition,
            modalHeight: modalHeight,
            modal: modal)
        )
    }
}
```

Here the modal is displayed by an offset from a viewModier, and the opacity is controlled uniquely with the state change.
Also the view modifier helps us to extract the sheet display logic into a nice and short modifier.

[image: Pouf]

Comment: Thanks for your propositions that's what I wanted. But as I asked to @Benzy Neez, there is no way to directly change the color of the present background ?

Comment: @neo
You can achieve this by not using the presentation sheet but by adding an overlay view with a bottom transition or some y offset.
Then as you can control the background as explained earlier. Have a look at the edit